# Is it possible to use 2 or more onwrite firebase cloud functions at the same time?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want my cloud function act differently according to where database write happen.

For example:

```
functions.database.ref('queues/login/{uid}').onWrite(event => {
//do something here
});
functions.database.ref('queues/login/{uid}/status').onWrite(event => {
//do another thing here
});
functions.database.ref('queues/login/event').onWrite(event => {
//do something else
});
```

is this possible? if not and i have to collect them all in 1 onwrite trigger how can i do this with an if clause?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely have more than one database trigger defined in the same project.  You can even have more than one trigger defined at the exact same location.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, the 3 Functions are aiming to the same node `login`. This would be the order to happen when any client write something on `queues/login/{uid}`

1. The uid as key will be written with whatever is it pair value
2. The first Functions will be activated
3. If the value included the `status` then the second Function will also be activated

Eventually, something will happen that will write on this `queues/login/event` and the 3rd Function will be triggered.

Is also interest to point that, Functions can trigger other Functions. So you can also create a sort of cascade to achieve your goal.

Finally, I notice you are only using `write`, maybe you can refine your listeners using `create` for some of those.